# Get the permalink from a loop displaying custom taxonomy titles and images

Tags: php, wordpress, url, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called projects and a custom taxonomy attached to that called sectors. I have also added the ability to add an image to each taxonomy using Advanced Custom Fields.

I'm displaying a list of the sectors on the homepage of my site which consists of the title of the taxonomy along with its image here:

[image]

So far, so good...

I'm struggling with surrounding either the image or title with the permalink for the taxonomy. I'd like to be able to click on it and it takes me to a page showing all of the projects inside that sector.

My loop is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row no-gutters">

    <?php
        // loop through terms of the Sectors Taxonomy
        $getArgs = array(
        'parent'       => 0,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'hide_empty'    => false,
        );
        // get the taxonomy we are going to loop through. 
        $taxonomy = get_terms('sectors', $getArgs);
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

    // Start the loop through the terms
    foreach ($taxonomy as $term) { 

        // Get acf field Name
        $image = get_field('sector_image', $term ); 
        $url = $image['url'];
        $title = $image['title'];
        $alt = $image['alt'];
        // which size?
        $size = 'large';
        $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
        ?>

        <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="sector-item-container" style="position: relative;">

            <div class="box-overlay"><?php echo $term->name; ?></div><!-- box overlay -->

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
            </a>

        </div>
        </div>

<?php } // end foreach ?>

</div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding tags like this around the elements I want to be clickable:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
</a>
```

But they don't seem to pull the links through...

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any insight at all :)

***** EDIT ***************

This seems to show a list of the taxonomies and also apply the link to them... so it's somehow a mix of both I need I think, this following code works but without the images!...

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'sectors';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
    <div class="container-flex">
    <div class="row no-gutters">

        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="sector-item-container" style="position: relative;">


                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <div>  
                           <?php  
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('page-thumb-mine');
                            }
                            ?>

                            <?php 

                            $image = get_field('sector_image');

                            if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </a>


                    <div class="sector-item-title">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
                            <h4><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>


        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: First, check that your query is getting the results you expect. Put this under $taxonomy = get_terms('sectors', $getArgs);

<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($taxonomy,1).'</pre>'; ?>  

If this is giving you the results you expect, then pass the Post ID to things like "the_permalink()" because the default is the global post.  For example, the_permalink($term['ID']), or whatever the ID is for the current iteration.

Comment: Hi Jarom, thanks for answering - it seems its getting: name, slug, term_group, term_taxonomy_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count, filter - So no mention of URL or however its referred too...

Comment: I guess the next queston is: Why the query isnt getting the URL or permalink?

Comment: Taxonomies might be different than standard links (I usually debug this when working on this, so I don't have it memorized).  Try get_term_link(), but put in your taxonomy ID.  For example, <?php echo get_term_link($term['term_taxonomy_id']); ?>  This would go inside of your foreach iteration.

Comment: I'm really sorry Jarom, I'm not quite getting it... I've posted some more code in the question above - this was my original which works with the taxonomy name and pulls the link through, but doesn't bring the pictures in - I think I somehow need a combination of the two.

Comment: If that is working, then just retrieve the ACF with the ID in your loop.  echo $image = get_field('sector_image', $id_of_term_or_post_or_whatever);

Answer (score 1):

This is from the codex on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'species' );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

For your specific case, try swapping the above with this: $terms = get_terms( 'sectors' );

Edit:
As for your images, retrieve them with get_field('sector_image', $id_of_term_or_post_or_whatever);  Be sure to echo it.

```
 $image = get_field('sector_image', id_of_term_or_post_or_whatever);
 echo $image; //this might be $image['url'] or whatever, depending on how you set up ACF
```

Comment: Do you mean to add that to the last bit of code I posted in the edit? Where would it go exactly? and would: $id_of_term_or_post_or_whatever refer to would that by the the CPT of projects?

Comment: That works perfectly by the way, gives me the list of terms and the link, but its the images im struggling with... or combining the two - I seem to be able to get them working with either the images OR the link but not both

Comment: I think I managed it! See answer below - I combined the terms with the longer bit of code I had and it seems to now pull the images AND the links! Thanks for all of your help Jerom!!

Comment: On the taxonomy where you put your images, what is the ID?  ACF "get_fields" will pull in the current global POST, but if you are grabbing that information outside of that default WP query, then it needs to be grabbed with the ID of the post, taxonomy, page, etc.  You need to put in the ID in that second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I actually managed to combine the two bits of code like this and it seems to work!

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'sectors';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
    <div class="container-flex">
    <div class="row no-gutters">

        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
            $image = get_field('sector_image', $term ); 
            $url = $image['url'];
            $title = $image['title'];
            $alt = $image['alt'];

            $size = 'large';
            $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
        ?>



            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="sector-item-container" style="position: relative;">


                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
                        <div>  
                            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </a>


                    <div class="sector-item-title">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
                            <h4><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>


        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```